DiffMerge: Identical Files Marked As Inequivalent
I am comparing two folders, one I pulled down from GitHub and one that I've been working on locally and would like to push. DiffMerge displayed the files as different, as expected, so I went in and merged them. The content in the files is now the same, but when I exit the Edit View and go back to the Folder View in DiffMerge it still highlights them as not matching. When I click on them again, it tells me the files are identical under the current RuleSet.
Is this a glitch in Diffmerge's Folder View? Or are my files somehow subtley not the same?

Unix vs Windows end of line differences perhaps? ISTR I've had them fail for having a ^z (Windows EOF character on the end).

It is ignoring line separator differences in the ruleset, but it doesn't look like it's applying the ruleset at the folder diff level, just the file diff level. If we go to File > Change Ruleset from the main folder diff view, it's disabled.
